# Network Bandwidth Estimates for XenApp Published Applications

Tags: xenapp

This is probably a loaded question based on a myriad of assumptions, but does anyone know of some additional guidance or test results for estimating the Network Bandwidth needs for applications published via XenApp?

The best I could find was in this [document](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/616-102-671421/ICA_Client_Bandwidth_Analysis.pdf) (page 19 - TypeData_01), which as I understand, estimates an average of 3732 bytes per second (8 * 3732 = 29,856 bits per second) for a published copy of Word doing text-based use cases with no client tuning.

Without knowing much about XenApp, or doing a test of my own, for some reason this somewhat feels about right, but wanted to see if anyone else had thoughts or comments.